# Python PlainText further processing?

Tags: python, text

I am learning python and I have a thought about a personal usecase. I want to scan and document shopping receipts.
Hi have a scanned pdf of a receipt.

I get the text as a plain text.

Code

```
reader = PdfReader(path_pdf)
number_of_pages = len(reader.pages)
page = reader.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
```

result

```
            REWE xxxxxx       
          xxxxxxx street          
         xxxx CIty        
        Telefon xxxxxx       
         UID Nr.:xxxxxxx        
                                   EUR
BAGUETTEBROET.                   0,17 B
LAUGENSTANGE                     1,49 B
KART.SALAT EI/GU                 1,49 B
NATIV. OLIVENOEL                 5,99 B
NIVEA SF CS                      0,69 A
LUXUS TOILET.PAP                 3,95 A
SODA CO2 FUELL B                 7,99 A
LEERG. MW V. ST                 -0,88 A *
            11 Stk x    0,08
LEERGUT EINWEG                  -1,25 A *
             5 Stk x    0,25
 --------------------------------------
 SUMME                   EUR     19,64
 ======================================
 Geg. VISA               EUR     19,64
                    
          * *  Kundenbeleg  * *          
Datum:                        30.06.2022
Uhrzeit:                    12:31:21 Uhr
```

I want to get data differntly like, some "headdata" of each receipt:

```
            REWE xxxxxx       
          xxxxxxx street          
         xxxx CIty        
        Telefon xxxxxx       
         UID Nr.:xxxxxxx      


 SUMME                   EUR     19,64

Datum:                        30.06.2022
Uhrzeit:                    12:31:21 Uhr
```

And the detailed article data:

```
                                       EUR
BAGUETTEBROET.                   0,17 B
LAUGENSTANGE                     1,49 B
KART.SALAT EI/GU                 1,49 B
NATIV. OLIVENOEL                 5,99 B
NIVEA SF CS                      0,69 A
LUXUS TOILET.PAP                 3,95 A
SODA CO2 FUELL B                 7,99 A
LEERG. MW V. ST                 -0,88 A *
            11 Stk x    0,08
LEERGUT EINWEG                  -1,25 A *
             5 Stk x    0,25
```

All that i want to store in some json and/or database.

Until now I have just worked with pandas to transform data.
What would be a good to work with this plain text?

If I could bring it into a dataframe I think I could get the data I need.
But I dont know how to get this plain text into a df.
Or is there any other way?
Some keywords how I could work with data would be really helpful.

Comment: This question is very broad and contains multiple questions inside it. Generally, questions asking for tutorials or libraries are explicitly off=topic for stack overflow, as we ask that you do your own research and attempt a [mcve] with code so that we can give specific answers to a specific question.

Comment: I will have done iterations on each line and I will have passed interested value in a dict to finally make a fresh dataframe and this is probably the only way to go

Comment: For example, python has good [documentation for the built-in file read and write functionality](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) which would be a good place to start. There's also the csv module if you want to treat it as data, or the header or skiprows parameters when reading in via pandas

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look on regular expression. In python its the 're' module. Iterate through the text line by line and scrap the date of interest with a regex.  https://regex101.com is a good playground for writing regular expressions.

Comment: it is plain text so you can use all `string` functions for this, For example in your example there is empty line between header and prices, and empty line between prices and footer - so you coul use `split("\n\n")` to split it.

Comment: ok. Thank you all for you input. I will try it all and improve my skills!